# iphone - How to control CALayer's shadow, exactly?

Tags: iphone, calayer, shadow

I am very new to CALayer thing. I had a look at the documentation, but quite don't understand the meaning of those properties which can be used to control the shadow

*shadowOpacity*

*shadowRadius*

*shadowOffset*

I particularly don't understand the Offset & Radius.

Can anyone give me some lights to me, for this newbie question?

Another question about the shadow is

If the UIView view1's frame is CGRect(0, 0, 768, 40), if I apply shadow on it, will the shadow possibly be covered by another UIView which is just next to the bottom edge of view1?

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The offset is how far the shadow is cast from its view.  The radius is how blurry it is.  You could set an offset that is zero CGSizeMake(0,0) and a radius of 5.0 and you would have an even shadow around your view.

Remember to import the QuartzCore library when trying to work with CALayers.

The shadow may be covered by views that are above it in the view heiarchy.

Comment: thanks @Dancreek. what you mean by even shadow? you mean like a bigger square of shadow all around my view? what if I use CGSizeMark(0, 3)? I don't know what's the meaning of x and y in shadowOffset.

Comment: also could you please tell me what Offset I should set if I just want my view's bottom edge having shadow?

Comment: x and y are directions.  Just like specifying points.  If you want the shadow to go a little to the right use a positive x value.  negative for left.  for down use a positive y value and negative for up.  So a 0,3 offset would give you a shadow cast straight downward.  By even I mean that it would stick out the same on all sides with a 0,0 offset and some radius larger than 0.

Comment: Just play around with these values and see what happens.